# Use multiple CA certs with python requests

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate, ca

I'm in a corporate network and need to use a self-signed certificate for the requests library
in a docker image.

I installed it by putting it in `/usr/local/shares/ca-certificates` and calling `update-ca-certificates` like this:

```
COPY EDAG_Bundle.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my_cert.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
ENV REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my_cert.crt
```

Now I am able to access files on a Server in our corporate network without running in a certificate error.
Unfortunately this change caused `pip` to stop working. As `pip` is using `requests` too, it also now uses the self signed certificate instead of the one from `certifi`.

The `requests` documentation states the following:

> You can pass verify the path to a CA_BUNDLE file with certificates of trusted CAs:
>
> requests.get('https://github.com', verify='/path/to/certfile')
> This list of trusted CAs can also be specified through the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable.

As I get this, I can define a List of trusted CAs, not just one.
How can I configure requests to use both CAs? (my self signed one and the one of `certifi` located in
`/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`).
Setting both in the environment variable by seperating the paths with a colon does not work.

Comment: Simply put all the certificates in the bundle after each other, not only a single one.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich how to put all certificates in one bundle ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` as your `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`.

```py
requests.get('https://github.com', verify='/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt')
```

When you put a self-issued CA certificate to `/usr/local/shares/ca-certificates`, then run `update-ca-certificates`, it will read those in and *append* to the global "ca trust file" (`ca-certificates.crt`). This will hold trust for both publicly trusted and your self-installed CA-s.

Note: Debuan/Ubuntu systems, CentOS/Alpine probably have this in a different location ([ref](http://ca.bigbank.eu/)).